# Unknown Behavior of Print Statement

Tags: python

I am very new to the python and playing around the print statement and found something unexpected.

```
print(0.3 + 0.1==0.4)

ANS : True
```

but when I tried

```
print(0.2 + 0.1==0.3)

ANS : False
```

[image]

Could Any one explain why is this so?
Thanks

Comment: This has nothing to do with `print`.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to [floating point math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic), not Python's `print` statement. You can see this for yourself if you go into the Python REPL.

```
>>> .2 + .1
0.30000000000000004
>>> .3 + .1
0.4
```

When comparing floating point numbers, always use an epsilon:

```py
epsilon = 1E-6
print(0.3 - (0.2 + 0.1) < epsilon)  # prints True
```

Comment: The built in round() function is easier. round(0.2+0.1,6) is equivalent to using 1E-6 as an epsilon.